# JavaFX: How to check if page available or not

Tags: java, web, javafx

In my project I use simple JavaFX browser, that works in background and do some stuff without displaying it.

More precisely it submitted some form to one online page.

So, I ran into a problem: when this page doesn't available, I can't figure it out from my Java code, it looks like form wasn't submitted and clicks on Submit button do nothing, but in Chrome for example I see that the page isn't available.

So, is there an option to check from Java code if page is available?

Thanks in advance and sorry for bad English.

Comment: Posting relevant code would help

Comment: @SirajK actually, I don't know what part of code I should post, because problem is not in my actual code, but in fact that I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Why do you use a webview to submit a form instead of sending the right http POST/GET request ??

Comment: @user43968 Unfortunately I have to do it this way ,submitting the form trigger redirection on web page I handle event on, using `WebEngine#executeScript`

Comment: re-read your course paper, I'm sure it contains the info you need to solve this ;) If you get stuck, provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @kleopatra this problem isn't linked with any course paper, but if you have something that would help me I'd really appreciate it.
And as I commented above, problem not in my actual code, so I can't provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found an answer.

There is `Worker` class in JavaFX that associates with `WebEngine` and it has a field with `State` type.
`State` is enum that has 6 options:

```
READY
SCHEDULED
RUNNING
SUCCEEDED
CANCELLED
FAILED
```

So `State.FAILED` can be used for handling errors.

For example, something like that (we'll assume we have `WebEngine` instance):

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldState, newState) -> {
  if (newState == Worker.State.FAILED) {
    doOnError();
    return;
  }
  doOnSuccess();
});

webEndgine.load("example.com");
```

So, every time state is changed `ObservableValue#changed` will be called with new `State` value as one of parameteres and if state become `FAILED` we do some error processing.